# How to convert 2D arrays in dictionary into one single array?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

num_seq = 100
len_seq = 20
nts = 4
sequences = np.random.choice(nts, size = (num_seq, len_seq), replace=True)
sequences = np.unique(sequences, axis=0) #sorts the sequences

d = {}
pr = 5

for i in range(num_seq):
    globals()['seq_' + str(i)] = np.tile(sequences[i,:],(pr,1))
    d['seq_' + str(i)] = np.tile(sequences[i,:],(pr,1))

pool = np.empty((0,len_seq),dtype=int)
for i in range(num_seq):
    pool = np.concatenate((pool,eval('seq_' +str(i))))
```

I want to convert the dictionary `d` into a Numpy array (or a dictionary with just one entry). My code works, producing `pool`. However, at bigger values for `num_seq`, `len_seq` and `pr`, it takes a very long time.

The execution time is critical, thus my question: is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Just a total side-note here, you're overwriting the `dict` class with `dict = {}`. Might not be a big deal but generally not a great convention.

Comment: I's better to collect arrays in a list, anddo `concatenate` once on the list.  Repeated concatenates 1 at a time is slower.

Comment: What's the purpose of updating `globals()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of important points:

- `np.concatenate` runs in `O(n)` so your second loop is running in `O(n^2)` time. You can append the value to a list and `np.vstack` all the values in the end (in `O(n)` time).
- accessing `globals()` is slow and known to be a bad practice (because it can easily break your code in nasty ways);
- calling `eval(...)` is slow too and also unsafe, so avoid it;
- the default CPython interpreter does not optimize duplicated expression (it recompute them).
- You can use Cython to slightly speed up the code or Numba (note that the support of dictionaries is experimental in Numba).

Here is an example of faster code (in replacement of the second loop):

```py
pool = np.vstack([d[f'seq_{i}'] for i in range(num_seq)])
```